# Elfinderd: php file manager connector.php

Tags: php, path, elfinder

I am trying to add http://elfinder.org which is the most professional php file manager on the web, i have uploaded the file in a subfolder http://example.com/admin but the connector does not work

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path'          => '../files/',         // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'accessControl' => 'access'             // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        )
    )
);
```

in my web-host panel this is the address to my account
**/dns/in/olympe/moderactif**

but I really can't set the correct paths

Can you help me?